# Store function names in a data.table and then those execute functions using lapply

Tags: r, function, parsing, data.table

I'm toying with the idea of storing functions that I plan to execute in a data.table, with the actual functions being elsewhere in the code, and then calling each of them up using lapply and executing them. I've tried a few things, such as `get` and `do.call`, but those seem to only accept lists. Now I'm trying to figure this out using `parse`/`eval`.
Is there another way that I might be able to extract the function name from the data.table and then execute the function that shares the same name as the extracted value?
Here is my latest attempt below:

```
library(DT)
library(data.table)

conds <- setDT(data.table(
  c(    "Func1",    "Func2",    "Func3",    "Func4"), #column 1
  c(    7,  7,  7,  7), #column 2
  c(    0,  8,  15, 22), #column 3
  c(    7,  14, 21, 28) #column 4
))

lapply(1:nrow(conds), function(f) {
  func <- conds[[f, "V1"]]
  
  funcAsText <- deparse(func)
  
  newMyFunc <- eval(parse(text=funcAsText))
  
  newMyFunc()
})

Func1 <- function(x) {
  x <- 1
  print(x)
  }

Func2 <- function(x) {
  x <- 1+1
  print(x)
}

Func3 <- function(x) {
  x <- 1+2
  print(x)
}

Func4 <- function(x) {
  x <- 1+3
  print(x)
}
```

Comment: for its first argument (the function), `do.call` accepts a function symbol (e.g., `mean`), an anonymous function, or a string that resolves to a function name. The only requirement for a `list` is in the second argument, `args=`, and that should be easy enough with `do.call(V1, list(somearg))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a function name as a string, use `getFunction` to get the actual function

```
lapply(1:nrow(conds), function(f) {
  func <- conds[[f, "V1"]]
  newMyFunc <- getFunction(func)
  newMyFunc()
})
```

Comment: `get` should also work?

Comment: If you want a function `getFunction` is more explicit. It would work in the case where you did something like `mean <- 5` then` getFunction("mean")` would still return the mean function but `get("mean")` would return 5. But it's the same basic idea.

Comment: So your solution was working for a while until I restarted my R session. Now I'm getting this error message:
`Error in getFunction(func) : no function ‘Func1’ found`. Do you have any ideas why it would stop working?

Comment: Actually, I just rearranged the script. The part that you gave is now at the bottom after the functions are declared, and it works perfectly. Thanks!